# how does openfire server behave when one recipient got packet from multiple sender at the same time?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I am newbie in xmpp(openfire server). I trying to make a application where multiple user can write or sketch at the same time on their client application and the coordinates will be passed to all the active group members. so in that case there is a very possible case when one user have to receive many coordinates from different user at the same time. How this will be handled by server? will only one packet be passed at one time? and other packet will be dropped? if so, what kind of mechanism should be used? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why would you think packets would be dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP is serial in nature, the client receives a stream of stanzas so it will get the messages one at a time and the server should not drop any packets.

i highly recomend this book if you are doing any XMPP work.  [XMPP: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521271.do)

Comment: the server send messages serially..and if server does not drop any packet ..then the server use some kind of buffer?

Comment: In a simplistic view of a server in general, it will read data from one endpoint, put in in a queue, and another thread will read it and write it out to another endpoint.  There is, of course a lot of other stuff done with regards to routing and such, but yes, buffers are used.